# i am getting some unreported values in my program

Tags: c, file

My program is to ask the user to enter the name and age of the person in his group. The number of person is not known to the user in the beginning of the program. The user keeps on entering the data till the user enters the age **zero**. The program finally prints the average age.

The source code is below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
typedef struct group {
    char user_Name[21];
    int user_age;
}Group;
int main()
{
    Group  *REC1;
    FILE *out_file, *read_file;
    int count_age=0, age, sum_age, i;
    float avg_age;
    char name[21]="", str[21]= "details.txt";
    char sample_chr;
    //opening a file in writing mode
      out_file = fopen(str, "a");

    // test for files not existing. 
       if (out_file == NULL) 
       {   
           printf("Error! Could not open file\n"); 
           exit(-1); // must include stdlib.h 
       }

       printf("\nEnter the Details of the person:\n\n");
       do
       {
         printf("Enter the User Name:\n");
         fflush(stdin);
         scanf("%[^\n]",name);

         printf("Enter the Age:\n");
         fflush(stdin);
         scanf("%d",&age);


         if(age == 0)
         {
            break;

         }
         else
         {
            // write to file 
            fprintf(out_file,"%s,%d\n", name, age);
         }

       }while(1);

       read_file = fopen(str,"r");
            //counting the number of lines present in the above file
             sample_chr = getc(read_file);
             while (sample_chr != EOF)
             {
                if (sample_chr == '\n')
                   count_age = count_age +1;

               sample_chr = getc(read_file);
             }             
             rewind(read_file);

             //allocating space for array of structure dynamically
             printf("\n%d\n",count_age);
            count_age = count_age - 1;
             REC1  =  (Group*)malloc(count_age*sizeof(Group));

             //storing the values in array of structures
             for(i=0; i<=count_age; i++)
                fscanf(read_file, "%s,%d", REC1[i].user_Name, &REC1[i].user_age);


             fclose(read_file);
             fclose(out_file);
             for(i =0; i<=count_age; i++)
             printf("\n%s %d\n", REC1[i].user_Name, REC1[i].user_age);

             for(i=0, sum_age=0; i<=count_age; i++)
              sum_age = sum_age + REC1[i].user_age;

             avg_age =  (float)sum_age/(count_age);

            printf("\n\nThe average age is %f\n\n\n", avg_age); 



    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

while i am compiling it doesn't shows any error. When i am running it shows exe file stopped working.

Comment: Just because it compiles doesn't mean it will work. All that means is it's valid code, not *correct* code.

Comment: Now is the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` ....yikes

Comment: One thing that stands out though: The C specification explicitly mentions calling `fflush` with an input-only stream (like e.g. `stdin`) to be *undefined behavior*. It's probably not the cause of the problem you have though, you have to debug to find it.

Comment: @Sam Learning C effectively means learning how a debugger works. Step through your code, observe what values are being set, and when a problem occurs, look very closely at what might have caused the problem.

Comment: i have to submit my records by tomorrow. Well i would love to execute but not in a state

Comment: @Sam - You lack of planing is of no consequence to any of us.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following is working

there had to be changed the format in `scanf()` of `name[]` ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ )

, the `fclose(out_file)` had to be moved and the ending condition of the while loop had to be changed ...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

typedef struct group {
    char user_Name[21];
    int user_age;
}Group;

int main()
{
    Group  *REC1;
    FILE *out_file, *read_file;
    int count_age=0, age, sum_age, i;
    float avg_age;
    char name[21]="", str[21]= "details.txt";
    char sample_chr;
    //opening a file in writing mode
      out_file = fopen(str, "w");

    // test for files not existing. 
       if (out_file == NULL) 
       {   
           printf("Error! Could not open file\n"); 
           exit(-1); // must include stdlib.h 
       }

       printf("\nEnter the Details of the person:\n\n");
       do
       {
         printf("Enter the User Name:\n");
         scanf("%21s[^\n]",name);

         printf("Enter the Age:\n");
         scanf("%d",&age);


         if(age == 0)
         {
            break;

         }
         else
         {
            // write to file 
            fprintf(out_file,"%s , %d \n", name, age);
         }

       }while(age != 0);

       fclose(out_file);

       read_file = fopen(str,"r");
            //counting the number of lines present in the above file
             sample_chr = getc(read_file);
             while (sample_chr != EOF)
             {
                if (sample_chr == '\n')
                   count_age = count_age +1;

               sample_chr = getc(read_file);
             }             
             rewind(read_file);

             //allocating space for array of structure dynamically
             printf("\n Number of group members : %d \n",count_age);
            count_age = count_age - 1;
             REC1  =  (Group*)malloc(count_age*sizeof(Group));

             //storing the values in array of structures
             for(i=0; i<=count_age; i++)
                fscanf(read_file, "%s , %d", REC1[i].user_Name, &REC1[i].user_age);


             fclose(read_file);

             for(i =0; i<=count_age; i++)
             printf("\n Name : %s   Age : %d \n", REC1[i].user_Name, REC1[i].user_age);

             for(i=0, sum_age=0; i<=count_age; i++)
              sum_age = sum_age + REC1[i].user_age;

             avg_age =  (float)sum_age/(count_age);

            printf("\n\nThe average age is %f\n\n\n", avg_age); 



       return 0;

}
```